# Concatenate column text heading if 2 column totals equal

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have three columns, each with a  heading lets call them: **column a**, **column b** **column c**. Each column has 10 questions which total at the bottom.

IF the total for 2 columns equal then concatenate the column headers together and insert an "or" in between.

i.e. if column a = 9 and column b = 9 and column c = 6, then concatenate column a or column b

The result to read: **column a or column b**

nb: the "or" in the middle of the two concatenated text is important

the formula I am using concatenates the text but does not add the **"or"** in-between the text.

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(MAX(A10:C10)= A10, "COLUMN A", ""), IF(MAX(A10:C10)= C10, "COLUMN B",""), IF(MAX(A10:C10)= C10, "COLUMN C",""))
```

[Concatenate Query](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5o8eg56zqoqaram/Concatenate%20question.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: All this makes very little sense. Share a workbook with your data. Show the "before" and the "after" scenario. Explain the logic. Use better column names than "col A", "col B" etc. Use one of the gazillion free file sharing services to post your sample file.

Comment: And you only want to concatenate the column names if those column totals are the `max` total value?

Comment: @topsig Yes. I have attached "Concatenate Query" file for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of doing what you've asked using nested `IF` and `AND` statements

Assuming the `sum` of each column is in row `12`, and the column headings are in cells A1, B1 and C1

```
=IF(AND(A12=MAX(A12:C12),B12=MAX(A12:C12)),A1 & " or " &  B1, IF(AND(A12=MAX(A12:C12),C12=MAX(A12:C12)),A1 & " or " & C1, IF(AND(B12=MAX(A12:C12),C12=MAX(A12:C12)),B1 & " or " & C1,"")))
```

For the general case where if you want to know if all three columns are equal, or if only one of them contains the `max` value, then expanding the `IF` statement gives

```
=IF(AND(A12=B12,B12=C12),A1 & " or " & B1 & " or " & C1,
IF(AND(A12=MAX(A12:C12),B12=MAX(A12:C12)),A1 & " or " &  B1, 
IF(AND(A12=MAX(A12:C12),C12=MAX(A12:C12)),A1 & " or " & C1, 
IF(AND(B12=MAX(A12:C12),C12=MAX(A12:C12)),B1 & " or " & C1,
IF(A12=MAX(A12:C12),A1,IF(B12=MAX(A12:C12),B1,C1))))))
```

Comment: this answer does not take into account the fact that we want the verify whether the **MAX** value in the range is equal to cell in question. Your formula ONLY compares if they are equal.

Comment: Yes. I agree with @AHC. Column cell text needs to be concatenated (with an "or" in between) if column total equal. Please see attached excel file.

Comment: @topsig - "Note that it doesn't handle the case if all three columns are equal" - this is also the case if only one column has the highest value; the result is blank... How can I have the name of one column?